# Find out the missing letters

Tags: letter-sequence

> A **?** I **?** O **?** U **?** W **?** Y

Here are some letters. Following the similarities you have to find out which letters will sit instead of the question mark and why?

Comment: Last 2 ?,? must be V,X respectively or are they out of order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The full sequence is

> A **H** I **M** O **T** U **V** W **X** Y

because

> All these letters have a vertical line of symmetry.

Comment: Couldn't understand the explanation.

Comment: @IQWANTER Flip each letter around a vertical line passing through its centre, and it remains the same.

Comment: Yea, that's correct. great